# Switch between data presentation in template of django

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, responsive

Im new to django.
I don't know if thing that I ask if available in pure django tempates.

I have main page of my application that load data from database.
It output information in `div` which then use bootstrap for better look.
In that div I have Image and Title.

Is there a way to give user ability to switch between `views` so they could pick if they like to have `div`'s or for example `table` with titles only ?

I know that ajax-based frameworks had something like that but never used them.

Also I would like to preserve data from model while switching view, because I would like to not ask db for data when view is switched.

Is it possible? or the only way to do it is make separate template and add `route` for /view/ so I redirect user to different page with different template and handle viewing as new page (with reloading model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a good practice but if you really want it to be in the same html file:

Using the Django Template LAnguage to evaluate which "view" the user wants.

Modify your html file to include this in the body.
First we make a form where we ask the user what view he wants and then we evaluate with data from the context dictionary

```
<form role="form" id="view_form" method="post" action="<same url>">
        <input type="radio" name="view" value="view1" checked> View #1 <br> <!-- this one will be checked by default -->
        <input type="radio" name="view" value="view2"> View #2 <br>
        <input type="radio" name="view" value="view3"> View #3 <br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Change View</button>
    </form>

    {% if view == view1  %}
        <!-- your code here -->
    {% elif view == view2 %}    
        <!-- your code here -->
    {% endif %}
```

Modify your view in views.py to capture and add the data from the form to the context dictionary.

```
def page(request):
    context_dict = {}
    if request.method=='POST':
        view = request.POST.get['view']
        context_dict['view'] = str(view)

    #The rest of your code here    
    ....
```

However I think it is better to evaluate the view value in your view function and render a different template for each value

```
def page(request):
    # Your code first

    view_value = None
    if request.method=='POST':
        view = request.POST.get['view']


    if view = 'view1':
        render(request, 'your_template.html', context_dict) # If you don't have a context, simply don't include it in this line
    elif view = 'view2':
        render(request, 'your_template2.html', context_dict)

    ... # All your other possible views

    else:
        render(request, 'default_template.html', context_dict) # If there's no match, load the default one.
```

Comment: In the future, please attempt to resolve the problem and post what you have, what you tried to do to solve it and what didn't work.
Not that I didn't enjoy coding this example anyways.

Comment: after disabling `csrf` it throw me an error : 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__' for  view = request.POST.get['view']

Comment: I was able to overcome those error with ```def index(request):
    context_dict = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        view = request.POST['view']
        context_dict['view'] = str(view)```  but it looks like it refresh the page and query db once again. Your code gave me few ideas. so thank you for that. It looks like I will have to redo my div-s with js-css solution that will transform objects with css or show/hide them if I want to avoid reloading page.

Comment: The error in my code was `context_dict = [ ]` , when it should have been `context_dict = { }`